# Joints for 105 degree angle?

Tags: joints

I am making a dodecagon (12-sided) garden planter. The 12 pieces are LHW 100mm x 63mm x 38mm. The angle of each is 105°

I'm looking for suggestions on what joint I can use.
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. There's no *should* here (as in most similar cases), it is completely up to the individual and their tools, skills/experience, and just plain personal preference (it's very common for someone to simply like one joint and use it by preference over other, similar/equivalent options). Given this is only a planter you're building you have the option to use no actual joinery, since you could simply screw the thing together.

Comment: What do you mean by *The angle of each is 105°*? The interior angles of a regular dodecagon are each 150°.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! I have added an image of 1 of the 12 pieces. I was thinking of a finger joint as it will look pretty down the side. Or a bridle joint. Just not certain if they will be strong enough.

Comment: The dimensions of each piece are LWH 100mm x 38mm x 64mm. It's along the 64mm edges where the join will be.

Comment: Finger joints are immensely strong, actually far stronger than I think this needs. If you're contemplating them I presume you have a TS or a router table already? This should have been specified in the body of the Q as needed/beneficial info for prospective Answer-writers.

Comment: Hi @Graphus thanks. I only have chisels. This is my project for a woodworking course. Hence my question and information being a little naive.

Comment: Ah in that case I would definitely discard the idea of finger joints. The thing about box joints/finger joints generally is that they're rarely (almost never) done by hand, even for straight 90° corners, and even in a pro setting — since they're actually about as difficult to do as dovetails if cutting by hand one would just go for the superior look and strength of the latter.

Comment: FWIW I would go with reinforced butt joints here given the compound angle, which is notorious for tripping people up (they're mind-benders). You can use exterior screws, the heads hidden in counterbores, or just go with my favourite option and that's through-dowels. These give virtually or exactly the same look as if you'd used screws, but require less work when drilling, and the hold strength is similar if you angle some or all of the dowels (giving a dovetail-like hold). Essentially all you have to do is butt the joints, hold them in position while drilling holes [contd]

Comment: ...and glue in your dowels. Saw off the excess after the glue has dried and flush by carefully paring with a very sharp chisel. Final sanding will smooth them out perfectly for a very neat appearance.

Comment: Love this idea! Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 4):

As noted in comments, you’ve got pretty much endless options.

Off the top of my head, here’s a few.

1- no joinery at all… use hoops (like a barrel) to hold everything together.

2- biscuits and glue… would require a biscuit joiner with a tiltable fence, or a benchtop jig.

3- dowels and glue… would also require a jig and a bit of precision.

4- screws and glue… you’ve got the material thickness. Easiest would be screwing from the exterior side, but that’s an aesthetic choice. You might be able to get the screws to work from the inside, but that might be tricky.

5- tongue and groove and glue… wouldn’t do this without a tablesaw or router table. (Though milling your staves without a tablesaw would be a curse.)

6- (waterproof) plywood splines and glue… slightly simpler than t&g, but still tool-heavy.

Glue should be waterproof, like titebond 2 or 3.

Comment: One thing I didn't think of yesterday re. your no. 3, it may be worth noting that this can be done without any jigs if through-dowels are selected. Far, far simpler — no mind-bending compound angles to try to work out and deal with! — quick to do and super super strong if the dowels are dovetailed in (not possible with blind dowels).